# a4j:commandButton returning from an action method loses css-styles

Tags: css, jsf, jsf-2, richfaces, commandbutton

I'm using Mojarra 2.1 and RichFaces.

I have the following action method:

```
public String doSave() {
    //do some
    return "someView";
}
```

invoked by cliccking the

```
<a4j:commandButton action="#{theBean.doSave}" />
```

and the view-file `someView.jspx`. But after the action method has invoked I'm redirected to the appropriate view, but lose all css-styles in that view. Actually, the head tag of the page is empty:

```
<head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
</head>
```

The `someView` page bounded to a session-scoped bean.

I have really no idea about what it can be tied with? Need some advice.

BTW, it works perfectly fine with `h:commandButton`. Is it a richFaces bug?

Comment: @BalusC Yes, sorry for that typo.

Comment: @BalusC So, is it possible to say something or I should provide more information?

Comment: I don't do RichFaces, so I can't tell from top of head. I'd basically have to test and debug it myself first after having the right versions/configuration/MCVE at hand (and having the time and motivation to actually do that). I was just trying to eliminate an ambiguity/redherring in your question so that you've more chance that the right audience passes by and can answer.

Comment: Is your css linked in template? Check if it in proper place: for example move it as first line in `<h:body>` in template.

Comment: Do you actually have `<head>` in your code or are you pasting output from the browser here?